# Need to embed new header menu in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration Form ,I Need to a new header menu after the successful user log-in. how to do this ? Can we integrate Different header menu for Different page(artical). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

First one that you could create two menus, one for registered and one for non-registered users and use different module after login.

Second option to use the same menu and set different items for each group. The selection could be made under:

```
Menus -> *Menu_Name -> *Menu_Item -> Access: Public / Registered
```

**EDIT:** In order to set menu items available only for non-registered users you have to select **Guest Access Level**: [Allowing Guest-Only Access to Menu Items and Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules).

Hope this helps

Comment: Log-in menu should be set for registered user or non-registered user ? if set registered user then new user con't access the log-in menu,and if set it as non-registered then it will available after user log-in all so . ( i want to hide log-in menu after user log-in )

Comment: You have to set all buttons that you want to be hidden after login to `Guest` level.

Comment: Ya Got it .but if i set log-in button as registered(because i want hide after log-in )then how new user will login?

Comment: ya i set it as a public only .but its displaying after user log-in all so . i want hide that button after log-in

Comment: Please set it as guest, tutorial could help you how to enable guest level.

Comment: but i have only 4 Viewing Access Levels those are :Registered/public/Special/Customer Access Level . (sorry i am new for Joomla ,sorry if i am giving lot of trouble )

Comment: Please follow the first step of the tutorial to create guest level.

Comment: i am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration Form .i need to redirect to 2 different pages after different type of user log-in .Can this possible ? .Now my log-in menu redirecting every user to one constant page After successful log-in . please help @emmanuel

Comment: That's not so easy, you have to make a big core change for that.

Comment: i got the solution by using log-in redirect component .